# Workday Apache Camel processor error while calling end point

Tags: apache-camel, workday-api

We were using Apachel Camel workday processor and it was working fine until July 16th. Workday made a change at thier end to allow TLS version 3 since then Workday camel processor is not able to connect directly to workday and gives the following error.

caught generic exception in route: stackTrace : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Got the invalid http status value 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized' as the result of the RAAS 'URL'
at org.apache.camel.component.workday.producer.WorkdayDefaultProducer.process(WorkdayDefaultProducer.java:71)

Whereas i debugged the code, i used the same token that the workday default producer java class is using and called the end point using postman which is working fine. Just a note that this code was working fine until 16th of july.